# Mount MTP Android Device in Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: mount, android, mtp

I to mount my ASUS Android device in Linux Mint 17.1 (MTP). My pc didn't see my device, so I tried following the answer in this page:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1077377

But when I click on "connect" I get the following error:

```
Listing raw device(s)
mtpfs: symbol lookup error: mtpfs: undefined symbol: LIBMTP_Detect_Raw_Devices
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 13):

**Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon 64-bit** or a recent Ubuntu/Debian distribution.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools
```

**Unplug the USB cable and reconnect your Android device.**

The Android device should now be recognised as expected.

---

***If you are still having problems, please try the following.***

Check if you have other MTP software installed, run the following in a terminal window:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep -i mtp
```

This will list any packages relating with MTP. You should only need ***mtp-tools*** installed for normal, everyday use.

Ignore any lines starting with "libmtp" and uninstall any other packages listed except **mtp-tools** for example with the following command replacing 'mtp-server' with what you have listed from the previous instruction.

```
sudo apt-get remove mtp-server
```

Then reinstall the mtp-tools package with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mtp-tools
```

You should now be able to access your Android device using MTP as expected from a Removable Storage device.

Comment: this didn't work for me

Comment: this did work for me (mpt-tools). Phone: Xperia Z3 conneted via cable/mtp, OS: Xubuntu 16.04

Comment: Worked for me. Make sure you are using a data cable not just on for charging, and click accept permission on the phone.

Comment: Wow, I was pretty convinced I had already tried everything (another computer, another phone?), and apparently just installing mtp-tools was enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Go to Synaptic Package Manager and install mtp-server. I use Linux Mint 17.1 Mate and my cell would not appear on my laptop, but after installing mtp-server it worked.

Comment: doesn't work. I installed the packages and rebooted the pc, but pc doesn't see the device.

Comment: This worked for me